# Url link to feature image in the portfolio

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I am new to Wordpress. i have issue with Feature image. just i need to add URL to feature image(when we click on that feature image , it should redirect to that particular URL).

also is it possible to give URL to Title of the Portfolio categories page which i used in normal page.

[image]

This is Portfolio , i have used in the "mypage" . so in that" mypage" when we click on that image and title it should be redirect to the link (should able to give individual link)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible with [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Add a custom fields, for example, named `link`. Put the link into the value field. Then you will be able to access it something like that:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'link', true ); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. from this code i can get redirect to the current page (which is in the Browser bar) but i want to redirect to URL which i had mentioned in the  EXTERNAL URL in the  Portfolio option(in the admin panel).

Comment: also in  portfolio page there is no Custom Fields.

Comment: Thanks Irina, its working fine. <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $sr_prefix.'_portfolio_externalurl', true); ?>"><?php } the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-crop-thumb');